# If statement for deleting in neo4j cypher

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

I am trying to only perform a detach delete based on two nodes containing the same value, and these two nodes receive parameterised values. Once this condition is true, it should run additional clauses.

I have gone through the Neo4j community pages and tried the FOREACH approach (https://community.neo4j.com/t/how-to-check-if-else-in-query/1533). However, from my researching it looks like you're only restricted to write-only clauses. The code below explains what I am trying to achieve, I only want to perform the delete action if the two User nodes are the same. I also tried an optional match such as

```
OPTIONAL MATCH (user: User)-[:CREATED]->(moment:Moment{GUID: $guid }) WHERE user.GUID = $userId
```

However, I somehow ended up deleting a series of nodes and ended up undoing the changes.

```
MATCH (user: User)-[:CREATED]->(moment:Moment{GUID: $guid })
MATCH (authUser: User{ GUID: $userId }) 

IF user.GUID == authUser.GUID:
  OPTIONAL MATCH (image:Image)-[:IS_ABOUT]->(moment)
  WITH image, moment, moment.GUID AS momentGuid, image.url AS url, image.GUID AS guid, image.filename AS filename
  DETACH DELETE moment, image

  RETURN COLLECT({
    moment: momentGuid,
    url: url,
    guid: guid,
    filename: filename
  }) AS data
```

Ideally the code under the if statement should only executed once the condition has been satisfied. Any advice would be greatly appreciated,

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a `MATCH` clause and its `WHERE` clause (if any) fails to match, then the entire query is aborted.

So, you can replace this:

```
MATCH (user: User)-[:CREATED]->(moment:Moment{GUID: $guid })
MATCH (authUser: User{ GUID: $userId }) 

IF user.GUID == authUser.GUID:
...
```

with this (simplified) snippet:

```
MATCH
  (user:User {GUID: $userId})-[:CREATED]->(moment:Moment {GUID: $guid}),
  (authUser:User {GUID: $userId})
...
```

*It is not clear what the remainder of your query is trying to do, so I am not commenting on that.*